# Cannot see mounted CIFS directory from FTP client

Tags: linux, windows, centos, mount, cifs

I have two servers, a Windows fileserver and a Linux FTP server.

I've mounted the directory from the Windows server into my home directory on the Linux server using CIFS:

```
mount -t cifs -o user=user,gid=1001,uid=1001,rw //ipaddress/dir /home/user/target-dir/
```

Now I want to access this "target-dir" using my ftp client, but the directory isn't shown from FTP client. Any ideas?

Comment: How does FTP figure into this?  Is one of these machines operating as an FTP server?

Comment: yes, I've mounted machine B with cifs method to machine A, and A was an FTP server. Mount point of machine B was inside the home directory of FTP user on machine A

Comment: When you're logged into the Linux machine via ssh, do you see that directory (and the files inside it)?  When you run the ftp client, do you see other files in the home directory?

Comment: Yes for the ssh. And for the FTP I see all folder inside home dir except my mounted dir.

Comment: Is there no one can solve my problem?

Comment: when linux double mount smb over ftp . I have encountered the same problem. are you solved this?  curlftpfs